# How to get the value of a cell based on filtering efficently

Tags: pandas

If I have a dataframe and want to have the value of a cell based on a condition/filter, it seems not to be a one line instruction.

In the example below I do not know the index at the beginning so I need to filter and then ask for index and apply it.

Is there a easier way to get the value without knowing the index upfront.

[image]

Edit: Easy spoken I want to have the value of the Column "Category" of the Row where the Column "No." has the value 'P1'.

Comment: Please explain better what are you after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with specify condition and column name:

```
out = dfn.loc[dfn['No.'] == 'P1', 'Category']
```

Then `out` is `Series`, with one or more values, if no match get empty `Series`.

If need first value of `out` to scalar:

```
scalar = out.iat[0]
```

But this fail if empty Series:

```
out = dfn.loc[dfn['No.'] == 'aaaa', 'Category']
```

Then use:

```
scalar = next(iter(out), 'no match')
```